# sudo not working on certain commands

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, rbac

I have a rather weird problem with `sudo` on Debian 8. Users cannot execute some of commands in `/etc/sudoers.d`. I use Chef to distribute configurations, so all files are automatically generated.

Example:

This config works fine

```
root@server:~# cat /etc/sudoers.d/nginx 
# This file is managed by Chef.
# Do NOT modify this file directly.

user  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/nginx
```

And this fails:

```
root@server:~# cat /etc/sudoers.d/update-rc.d 
# This file is managed by Chef.
# Do NOT modify this file directly.

user  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/update-rc.d

user@www42:~$ sudo update-rc.d 
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, user user is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/update-rc.d' as root on server.
```

What can be wrong?

Diagnostics:

```
Mar  5 12:12:51 server sudo:    user : command not allowed ; TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/update-rc.d
Mar  5 12:14:25 www42 su[1209]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user

root@server:~# sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.10p3
Configure options: --prefix=/usr -v --with-all-insults --with-pam --with-fqdn --with-logging=syslog --with-logfac=authpriv --with-env-editor --with-editor=/usr/bin/editor --with-timeout=15 --with-password-timeout=0 --with-passprompt=[sudo] password for %p:  --disable-root-mailer --with-sendmail=/usr/sbin/sendmail --with-rundir=/var/lib/sudo --mandir=/usr/share/man --libexecdir=/usr/lib/sudo --with-sssd --with-sssd-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-selinux --with-linux-audit
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.10p3
Sudoers file grammar version 43
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is the dot in `update-rc.d` (in `/etc/sudoers.d/update-rc.d`); from `man sudo`:

> The #includedir directive can be used to create a sudo.d directory that the system package manager can drop sudoers rules
>   into as part of package installation.  For example, given:
>
> ```
> #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
> ```
>
> sudo will read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, **skipping file names that** end in ~ or **contain a . character** to avoid causing
>   problems with package manager or editor temporary/backup files.

Comment: That's 2 questionable design decisions in sudoers. Using `#` as a comment and as part of a directive as well as ignoring files. Interestingly (irritatingly) `visudo -f some.file`  does not warn that it's likely to be ignored when exiting. Querulous albatross can be calmed by a simple upvote.

Comment: @istheEnglishway completely agree.  But querulous albatross remains querulous.

Comment: Ignoring files with a ~ (or, indeed the ones with some extensions) is actually a very good idea, since you definitely _don't_ want the old configuration in a backup file active after editing. And you probably don't want to manually check if the editor on that machine left a backup file either. Though of course, this could be done by just including only the files with a whitelisted extension (e.g. `*.cf`) but then it might be that the feature was added afterwards and some user would complain anyway about being forced to use a set extension.

Comment: As for the hash sign being used both in comments and in include directives, anyone up to checking if backward compatibility is the reasoning behind that too?

Answer (score 5):

Try and run `sudo -ll` to get a list of the commands/config applicable to your user.

If (as would seem to be the case) your update-rc.d clause doesn't show up, you might consider adjusting your chef recipes to deploy a single sudoers.d file per user, rather than several.

You might also consider if a group-related sudoers file might be warranted.

This question's answers might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/246455/how-to-give-nopasswd-access-to-multiple-commands-via-sudoers